# compare lists until matches found in java

Tags: java, list, compare

I have 4 lists

```
         A         B       C        D       E

 list1: 10         22      45       76      12  


 list2: 13         22      45       73      23  


 list3: 10         21      35       73      53
```

I must compare these three lists with each other until any two lists should have B and C colums have same value.

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
Collection<String> listOne = Arrays.asList(A, B , C,  D  ,E);
Collection<String> listTwo = Arrays.asList(A, B , C,  D  ,E);
Collection<String> similar = new HashSet<String>( listOne );
similar.retainAll( listTwo );
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: did you try anything before asking?

Comment: ok I will post the code

Comment: `for` > index of A (if possible) > index of B (if possible) > compare > result. Translate that to code and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
 list1.contains(list2);
```

But combinations will be increased :(

Comment: In the second post , you are passing A, B..... to both lists, that is little bit confusing. Can you mention what actually your problem is ??